# Where is the AWS .pem file stored on my local machine once it is used?

Tags: amazon-ec2, pem

I ssh’d Once into my ec2 using my pem. I noticed that I can SSH into my EC2 now without supplying my pem file anymore. So I’m assuming my pem file is stored somewhere on my local device and the SSH program is using a saved (cached) version of the  pem file on my local computer and is sending it with my ssh command to connect (otherwise how else is the connection happening)

If this is the case, does anyone know where the saved .pem file would be located on my local machine ?

Answer (score 1):

What's likely happening is that your PEM file is being loaded into a service called [ssh-agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent) that is running in the background. ssh-agent acts as a cache for your keys so that you don't need to specify them every time.

If you check your ssh config at `~/.ssh/config`(Note: MacOS), you may see something like:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The `AddKeysToAgent` setting in particular is what is causing the behavior that you're seeing. If you change that flag to `AddKeysToAgent no` and restart your ssh-agent by running:

```
ssh-agent -k
eval `ssh-agent`
```

You'll notice that you'll need to specify your PEM file every time, otherwise you will receive the permission denied error.

Also note that you can change the settings to only impact your server by adding a new `Host` section.